# Show one Item of a Library in two groups in its view

Tags: document-library, list-view, groups, view, sorting

I've got a requirement to show a single file in a document library in 2 predefined groups.
The View is first grouped by the column "Kunde" and sorted after "Dokumenttyp"
As you can see in this screenshot, I got a document, which should be in both groups "BBraun" and "SealTest". 
[image]

I've made "Kunde" a Choice - Checkbox Column and selected both values for the last document in the screenshot.

However, SP creates a new Group "BBraun, SealTest".

How do I come to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have selected Kunde as the column by which grouping is done, All the values entered in Kunde column will be a particular group. That is the default behaviour of grouping by columns.

Now if you want to have document present in both group, add the document twice, one by selecting BBraun and next time by selecting SealTest.

Or if you wish the user can select only one of the choices available, you can change the column settings to be radio button instead of check boxes.

If you cant have any of the above, The other option will be to create views with the option field name and having filter values based on options.

Comment: Hi Ankit, Thanks for your relpy. Adding the document twice is a bit impractical, because you need to maintain both instead of only one. I've chosen Checkbox, because I wanted it in both groups, but as we already figuered out this is not how it works. Switching back to Dropdown won't help either. I've also thought about views, but all files should get displayed in one view with expandable groups. But thanks anyway for your reply :)

Comment: There is another option coming in mind...having one calculated column in the list whose value will be updated based on the values selected in choice field...and then do the grouping based on this calculated column value

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the out-of-the-box view. I think you will need to either program it yourself or look for third-party solution.

BTW: I agree that duplicating the documents is out of the question. This will only lead to major confusion.

Comment: I'll post my solution as soon as I got one. Would upvote your post, but can't due to too less rep...